# Node.js's relations with other processes in terms of cpu

Tags: mysql, node.js, socket.io, cpu

I've had this question in my mind for a certain amount of time. I've tried to explore this but I didn't find anything useful. The question is;

Let's say that I've a server that has a 6 cored CPU and it's running a node.js app with socket.io in each and every one of that 6 core. Since node.js uses 100% off the attached CPU core, and every CPU core has been attached by a node.js application, would any other processes such as MySQL server be having any problems in terms of CPU usage? Or could it use one of the cores that node.js application had attached?

Comment: Only if all 6 processes use 100% CPU simultaneously, which is unlikely. Any way, if you're concerned with this scenario, you can save 1 core for other processes.

Comment: @estus I thought node.js applications would use 100% of a core even if there isn't any traffic going on

Comment: Of course not, that would be ridiculously inefficient. The same applies to any idle process. There can be 100% peaks but of course they aren't constant, as long as the app doesn't do any sync hard work (web server usually doesn't)